# Bootstrap site is not being responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

[Mobile view of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Z30.png)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.sidebar {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.content {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .jdzn-footer-text img {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .featured-card {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

I have already have the meta viewport tag, can anyone help me resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough information to go off to actually assist you on this issue. Your media query syntax is correct, so there's no error there. The rest comes down to how you've utilized Bootstrap and what you're trying to achieve specifically. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your viewport meta tag look like, but you may try replacing yours with this viewport meta tag in your index file.

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
</head>
```